# Vector in cyclic subspace such that $T^k(x)=w$

Tags: linear-algebra

Im having problems with the following exercise.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. Let $v$ be a non-zero vector of $V$. Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Suppose $w$ is a vector in the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$ (denoted $Z(T,v)$), such that $T^{m-k}(w)=0$ where $m = dim(Z(T,v))$ and $0 < k \leq m$. Prove that there exists a $x \in Z(T,v)$ such that $T^k(x)=w$.

So far my attempt is to write $w$ as $w = a_1v + a_2T(v)+ \cdots a_{m-1}T^{m-1}$ but I'm stuck here.

Edit: $Z(T,v)$ is defined as $span(v,T(v),T^2(v),\ldots,T^n(v),\ldots)$.

Comment: What can you say about the coefficients $a_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,m-1$,  using the given piece of information: $T^{m-l}(w)=0$?

Comment: Mind you, it would help readers, if you spelled out the meaning of the phrase *$T$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$*. I have a guess as to what it means, but you could share.

Comment: The coefficients may not all be zero, right?